# How to stop sale order confirmation email on specific payment Method in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to stop the order confirmation email on a specific payment method.

I can't achieve exactly which module perform email sending task and in 
which controller where I apply condition(email, sale, checkout).

Please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the class `Magento\Quote\Observer\SubmitObserver`, used in `Magento/Quote/etc/frontend/events.xml`.

You can override this class to add your test and avoid email sending.

Otherwise you can call the order function `$order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false)` with `false` as parameter when placing order.

Comment: Thanks for guide me.